# While typing on keyboard button tap doesn't get recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a problem with my iOS application. I want to implement something like a `MessagingViewController` where you got a `UITextView` and `Button` (sendButton) below an `UITableView`. If a tap the textView, the keyboard appears, the View goes up.. so far so good.

But, if I am entering random text and tab/press the send button (independent of what should happen now) while typing or if the time gap between typing and Button tab is to small, the tap doesn't get recognized. If you try iMessage or WhatsApp this isn't a problem.

I don't know what to do, I also tried CocoaPods like `SlackViewController` or `InputAccessoryView` but it is always the same problem. While typing, the button tap doesn't get recognized. I tried it with the normal `IBAction` of a `UIButton` and `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

I hope somebody can help me, this problem makes the UX horrible.

Thanks a lot!!!

Edit: Here's an example where the Button is in an `InputAccessoryView`.

```
import UIKit

class MessagingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var messages: [String] = ["12", "32"]
var accessory: UIView!
var cancelButton: UIButton!
var charactersLeftLabel: UILabel!
var sendButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var messagesTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TableViewCell.className, bundle:nil),
                       forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.className)
    addAccessoryView()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MessagingViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MessagingViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

    cell?.titleLabel.text = "Sender: \(indexPath.row): "
    cell?.detailLabel.text = messages[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}

func addAccessoryView() {
    let frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width,height: 45)
    accessory = UIView(frame: frame)
    accessory.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    accessory.alpha = 0.6
    accessory.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.messagesTextView.inputAccessoryView = accessory


    sendButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .disabled)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessagingViewController.sendButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    sendButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    accessory.addSubview(sendButton)
    let sendTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: accessory, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -20)
    accessory.addConstraint(sendTrailingConstraint)
    let sendCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: accessory, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    accessory.addConstraint(sendCenterYConstraint)
}

func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    messages.append(messagesTextView.text)
    messagesTextView.text.removeAll()

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your tried code here or like of github.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my project, it's works without any problem, add your code to see what you did. (i can't comment so i put this as an answer)

Comment: it's works perfectly... you can send me your project, I can test it.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't, did you test it on your phone or in simulator? For example you can checkout the cocoa pod "SlackViewController" there you got the same problem.. The send button doesn't react while typing.. In my example it's just a single view application, all I have is the viewcontroller I posted plus the storyboard file.. All connections between storyboard and view Controller are made.

Comment: Ok, i figured out that it works perfectly on an iPhone but not an iPad but I don't know why